# Re-releasing LGPL code as AGPL : need advice on how to phrase license

Tags: gpl, lgpl, agpl

I have written a compression codec that I am releasing under the AGPL.

I would like to link it with FFmpeg, a video streaming application. FFmpeg is
licensed under the LGPL, but since it supports some GPL v2 codecs, it can also be licensed under GPLv2. But not GPLv3.

So, in order to link my codec with FFmpeg, I will re-release FFmpeg under AGPL.

My question is : how to set up the license for this.

FFmpeg has two different license files to cover both LGPL and GPLv2.

I will now add a third AGPL license, which shall apply to all of the code
(Of course, the LGPL and GPLv2 licenses continue to be in force)

So, how do I word the AGPL to acknowledge the other two licenses ?

Thanks!!

Comment: i truly applaud the initiative! but i couldn't find any link to your beautiful work. do you even still work on this today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html#AGPLv3.0 :

> Please note that the GNU AGPL is not compatible with GPLv2. It is also
>   technically not compatible with GPLv3 in a strict sense: you cannot
>   take code released under the GNU AGPL and convey or modify it however
>   you like under the terms of GPLv3, or vice versa. However, **you are
>   allowed to combine separate modules or source files released under
>   both of those licenses in a single project, which will provide many
>   programmers with all the permission they need to make the programs
>   they want.** See section 13 of both licenses for details.

Emphasis mine.  According to http://ffmpeg.org/legal.html, ffmpeg is licensed under "GNU General Public License (GPL) version 2 **or later.**" So, I believe it is possible to make the bolded line relevant. Quoting the GPLv2 license,

> Each version is given a distinguishing version number. If the Program
>   specifies a version number of this License which applies to it and
>   "any later version", you have the option of following the terms and
>   conditions either of that version or of any later version published by
>   the Free Software Foundation.

I am not a lawyer and I make no promises that anything I said or emphasized is accurate, relevant, or trustworthy.  Consult a lawyer for legal advice.

Comment: Thanks, Brian. So, in my case, I can license FFmpeg as GPLv3, and then combine it with my AGPL code.

Comment: @Jacko: Maybe? If you want a confident answer, consult a lawyer.

Comment: @Brian not 100% correct - FFmpeg is licenced under the LGPL, but some (optional) parts are GPL.

Comment: @gbjbaanb: Per http://ffmpeg.org/legal.html, "If those parts get used the GPL applies to all of FFmpeg." See also, the section 3 of [LGPL 2.1](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.html): "You may opt to apply the terms of the ordinary GNU General Public License instead of this License to a given copy of the Library. "

Comment: I checked with FFmpeg, and they actually have a configure option "--enable-gpl3", so l can distribute FFmpeg under GPLv3, and then link with my AGPL component.

Comment: @Jacko: My understanding is that `--enable-gpl3` is not necessary to be permitted to distribute as gpl3.  Rather, `--enable-gpl3` forces the use of gpl3 (rather than LGPL) by including gpl3 components.  Of course, if you do want to use ffmpeg under gpl3, you probably should include such components.  However, the motivation in that case for using `--enable-gpl3` is to get a more full-featured ffmpeg, not to be compliant with the license.

Comment: do you have any idea what happened with jacko work? on a side note: i would love to see everyone migrating to agpl... please help to make it real!

Answer (score 5):

**You may not re-release Ffmpeg under AGPL**, as doing so imposes new restrictions on distribution, which is in violation of the original GPL license the software was distributed to you by.

Only the copyright holders of ffmpeg may create an AGPL licensed release.

Comment: +1, Though the argument is wrong. It is not because his license would impose new restrictions or not. It simply is because only the licencor can decide what licenses apply to the products (s)he has licensed for use to other people.

Comment: @MarjanVenema: The argument is right, but this does not contradict your statements.  The licensee can decide what licenses apply on condition that the licensor gave him permission to do so.

Comment: @MarjanVenema: no, it **is** because the AGPL would impose new restrictions. There are many licenses, such as MIT license, that **do** permit distributing it with additional restrictions, as the original terms set by the copyright holder only requires inclusion of the copyright notice and disclaimer of warranty. That's why MIT licensed software can be used in closed proprietary softwares, because the license permits the addition of further restrictions.

Comment: Unless the original licencor specifically allowed __re-licensing__ under equal or more restrictive terms, you are not allowed to re-license anything. Even though the GPL allows __re-distribution__ with software licensed under the same level of restrictions, this is not the same as __re-licensing__ the GPL'd software itself.

Comment: @MarjanVenema: that is not true. I can re-license MIT licensed code as I see fit as long as my new license also complies with the terms set by the original MIT license. It even explicitly says so in the body of the license: "the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,distribute, **sublicense**, and/or sell"". Again, the numerous examples of MIT software in proprietary software supports my claim even if you don't want to bother reading and understanding the licenses.

Comment: "It even explicitly says so in the body of the license" Isn't that what I said: "Unless the original licencor specifically allowed re-licensing"?

Comment: do you have any idea what happened with jacko work? on a side note: i would love to see everyone migrating to agpl... please help to make it real!

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg is [released under the LGPL](https://www.ffmpeg.org/legal.html), however some optional parts are GPL licenced, so you have a choice as a user of FFmpeg: to use the LGPL parts in a LGPL product, or to incorporate the GPL parts in a GPL product.

If you release under AGPL your codec will become part of the GPLd parts of FFmpeg, and will possibly confused the bejeesus out of people. This is probably not a good thing at all (just see the answers you've gotten already!)

I would say the nest approach would be to licence your codec as LGPL and then it will fit nicely into FFmpeg without any hassle. GPL would be clearer but then you'd be in the same category as x264 codec etc. AGPL will just cause confusion - is it really worth insisting on AGPL licencing given this?

Note if FFmpeg takes your codec, they will have to modify the build to exclude your codec when someone builds it in its default LGPL state.